# Where to find password for devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created model User with devise.
`$ rails generate devise User`
It has created table users.
I am not able to find password column in it. Where is password stored for users.

Answer (score 1):

It must be in column `encrypted_password`

Comment: there is no column in users table called `encrypted_password`

Comment: This is right answer. Devise generate migration file with column [`encrypted_password`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/active_record/devise_generator.rb#L43), after `bundle exec rake db:migrate` migration add columns to table.